# Add a user to a group programatically

Tags: rest, sdk, yammer

Is it possible to add a user to a group via REST/sdk?

Scenario: We want to add all our users to a mandatory group on a regularly basis.

Thanks!
Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.  This is by design.  Yammer likes to entice with the carrot, not by the stick.  What we've done is create communications to ask people to join a specific group.

The api does allow the ability for the currently logged to be joined to a specific group.  E.g. Put a link on a SharePoint site that says "Join the Yammer group", and have the action join that user to the group.  You can see the details for how to do that here:

https://developer.yammer.com/restapi/#rest-groups

Comment: I can understand why - but the solution is limited. We want to have one group with important management information. At first we thought we use the all company feed, but imagine you go to a 3 week vacation and have to scroll through all of the homefeed - not suitable for us. A separate, mandatory group would be better.

Comment: Why can't you ask people to subscribe to the group as part of your work process?  We can't force people to read their email, and a lot of times, people don't.  Once it becomes part of your work process, people become compelled to be part of that group.  Missing out on an important Yammer message is like missing out on an important email thread that you *should* have been part of, or missing an important recurring weekly meeting.

Comment: I can totally understand your points - they are all valid. Because they are member of the group does not make them read the important messages, but at least the get a notification that there is one. One manual step less is good and reduces the error rate - even tho its not "social" that you force someone in a group :)

Answer (score 2):

you can get group ids from share point list like this

```
 function GetMandatoryGroups() {
        var context;
        var factory;
        var appContextSite;
        var oList;
        var collListItem;

        context = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
        factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appweburl);
        context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
        appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostweburl);

        this.web = appContextSite.get_web();
        oList = this.web.get_lists().getByTitle('MandatoryGroups');
        context.load(oList);
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>');
        collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
        context.load(collListItem, 'Include(Title,Id)');

        context.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler),
            Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler)
        );

 function successHandler() {
            MandatoryGroups = new Array();
            var listItemInfo = '';
            var listitemenumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

            while (listitemenumerator.moveNext()) {
                var olistitem = listitemenumerator.get_current();
                //listItemInfo += '<li>ID:' + olistitem.get_id().toString() + ' GroupID: ' + olistitem.get_item('Title') + '</li>';
                MandatoryGroups.push(olistitem.get_item('Title'));
            }
            AutoJoinGroups();
            //  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = 'Lists found' +   oList.get_title() + ':<ul>' + listItemInfo + '</ul>';
        }

        function errorHandler(sender, args) {
            document.getElementById("message").innerText =
                "Could not complete cross-domain call: " + args.get_message();
        }
    }
```

you can join users to the mendatory groups like this (after user logs in )

```
      function AutoJoinGroups() {

        yam.platform.request({
            // yam.request({
            url: "groups.json?mine=1",
            method: "GET",
            data: {},
            success: function (group) {

                //for ($i = 0; $i < MandatoryGroups.length; $i++) {
                //    if (!ArrayContains(MandatoryGroups[$i].toString(), group)) {
                //        joinGroupAsync(MandatoryGroups[$i].toString());
                //        setTimeout('', 10000);
                //       // setTimeout(joinGroupAsync(MandatoryGroups[$i].toString()),5000);
                //    } 
                //}
                var i = 0;
                function AsyncAutoJoinLoop() {
                    if (i < MandatoryGroups.length) {
                        if (!ArrayContains(MandatoryGroups[i].toString(), group)) {
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                joinGroupAsync(MandatoryGroups[i].toString());
                                i++;
                                if (i < MandatoryGroups.length) {
                                    AsyncAutoJoinLoop();
                                }
                            }, 3000)
                        }
                    }
                }
                AsyncAutoJoinLoop();
                // getMyGroups();
            },

            error: function (group) {
                console.error("There was an error with the request.");
            }
        });
    }

    function joinGroupAsync(id) {
        yam.platform.request({
            // yam.request({
            url: "group_memberships.json?group_id=" + id,
            method: "POST",
            data: {},
            success: function (group) {

            },

            error: function (group) {
                console.error("There was an error with the request.");
            }
        });
    }
```

you can add group to the sharepoint list like this.

```
  function InsertMandatoryItem() {
        var context;
        var factory;
        var appContextSite;
        var oListItem;

        context = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
        factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appweburl);
        context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
        appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostweburl);

        this.web = appContextSite.get_web();
        var oList = this.web.get_lists().getByTitle('MandatoryGroups');

        var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
        oListItem.set_item('Title', InsertGroupId);
        oListItem.update();

        context.load(oListItem);
        context.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded),
            Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed)
        );
        function onQuerySucceeded() {
            //alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
            // getMyGroups();
            // AutoJoinGroups();
            $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.RequestExecutor.js', GetMandatoryGroups);

        }

        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.RequestExecutor.js', GetMandatoryGroups);
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
                '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
    }
```

You can remove remove group from sharepoint list like this

```
       function RemoveMandatoryGroup() {
        var context;
        var factory;
        var appContextSite;

        var collListItem;
        var itemId;
        context = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
        factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appweburl);
        context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
        appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostweburl);

        this.web = appContextSite.get_web();
        var oList = this.web.get_lists().getByTitle('MandatoryGroups');
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>" + RemoveGroupId.toString() + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");

        collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
        context.load(collListItem, 'Include(Title,Id)');


        //  this.oListItem.deleteObject();

        context.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded),
            Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed)
        );
        function onQuerySucceeded() {
            var oListItem;
            var listitemenumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

            while (listitemenumerator.moveNext()) {
                var itemtoDelete = listitemenumerator.get_current();
                ////listItemInfo += '<li>ID:' + olistitem.get_id().toString() + ' GroupID: ' + olistitem.get_item('Title') + '</li>';
                //MandatoryGroups.push(olistitem.get_item('Title'));
                itemId = itemtoDelete.get_id();

            }
            oListItem = oList.getItemById(itemId);
            oListItem.deleteObject();
            context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryDeleteSucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryDeleteFailed));
            //alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
            function onQueryDeleteSucceeded() {
                //alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
                //    '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
                getMyGroups();
                $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.RequestExecutor.js', GetMandatoryGroups);
            }

            function onQueryDeleteFailed() {
                alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
                    '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            }
        }

        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
                '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Interesting Solution, Mahesh.  Note that it requires that a user visit the site in question. I think the OP wants a way to bulk add a certain AD OU to a group, which this doesn't do, but it is probably the most creative way to get close.

Answer (score 0):

ya, in costume app yo can autojoin that user when he logs in..Same thing i ma doing.

Comment: Costume App? Can you share some details?

Comment: ya custom app. i am storing mandatory groupid to the sharepoint list and when user logs in then i will check that if user is member of mandatory groups or not. if not then join them to the group.

Comment: Check the above answer.